# Universal Apps 8.1 no Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, uwp

Windows 10 tem retro-compatibilidade com Universal Apps do Windows 8.1? Ou seja, os aplicativos escritos no para Windows 8.1 rodam no Windows 10?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, salvo alguma incompatibilidade não intencional que se descubra. O contrário já não é verdadeiro.

Comment: Já vi casos em que algumas plataformas até suportam retro compatibilidade com uma versão anterior mas fazendo-se necessário a recopilação do projeto na versão de destino.
Acredito que isso não se aplica a esse caso, bastando compilar uma única vez e podendo-se instalar em qualquer das duas versões.
Estou correto?

Comment: Com UWP é para funcionar, a Microsoft costuma cuidar muito bem disto.